# ошибка java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, intellij-idea

обычный java проект настроен, выводило Hellow World. Теперь пытаюсь создать апплет

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Applet{

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Hello, world!",0,50);
}

}
```

Вот так пытаюсь вывести приветствие
В консоле выводит ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Temp\AppletPage.html" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:844)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1121)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1092)
at sun.applet.Main.run(Main.java:156)
at sun.applet.Main.main(Main.java:98)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.main(AppletViewer.java:1275)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Собственно вопрос как получить доступ?

ide IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5

java version "1.8.0_111"

Comment: Я не эксперт, но апплеты же вроде являются чем-то вроде приложенек в браузере, поэтому логично, что из них с файловой системой работать нельзя, да и технология устаревшая

Comment: В универе лабы пошли...  не подскажете как связать IntelliJ IDEA и Open Server

Comment: Работаю и с тем, и с тем, но с апплетами не вожусь. По идее если вам нужно использовать openserver, то вы просто берете проект и кладете его в папочку домена, после чего запускаете опенсервер и в браузере открываете index.html по тому домену. Но тут сложно чем-то посоветовать, потому что я даже не понимаю смысл выражения "связать IntelliJ и OpenServer"

Comment: можно ли настроить так что бы ide не к файлу после компилирования, а к серверу обращалась?